# PHP file upload with ajax not updating the session[upload_progress] cookie

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, file-upload

### Quick version

Submitting a file upload form via AJAX results in no `$_SESSION[upload_progress]` array whereas normal submission does. How can I force creation/allow access to display a % completion of the upload. Are alternatives like iframes and XRH2 the best way to do this?

### Slow version

I have an upload function that uses `xmlHttpRequest` to upload multiple files by `upload.php`. These are then zipped in `upload.php`, and the database updated with the url of the zipped file.

Parallel to this, I have another `form` next to the first which submits directly to `upload.php` (to compare against) with the same processing (`upload.php`). The file uploading works for both, however I would like to get a progress % and have extra control via the `AJAX` form. I'm aware I could use [XHR2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491086/2276412) with the progress and load etc. event listeners, but I haven't had much luck with those, and I don't believe they are IE9 compliant anyway.

So instead I wanted to query the progress using a separate `AJAX` call, `uploadProgress.php`. I should be able to do that by using the session cookie, which creates various [session values](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) when a file is being uploaded.

```
<!--Standard form -->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="manualUpload" action="homeworkUpload.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="file-item" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="uploadFiles" multiple="multiple" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload your work</button>
</form>

<!--AJAX form -->
<form id="file-form" action="homeworkUpload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="file-item" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
    <input type="file" id="file-select" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</form>

<div id="bar_blank">0%</div>
```

**General AJAX function**

```
function loadXMLDoc(url,method="GET",fd="",cfunc) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else {xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;

    xmlhttp.open(method,url,false); 
    xmlhttp.send(fd);
}
```

**Main upload function**

```
document.querySelector("#file-select").addEventListener('change',function(e) {
    var files = fileSelect.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    document.getElementById('upload-button').innerHTML = 'Uploading...';

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        formData.append('files[]', file, file.name);
    }

    loadXMLDoc("homeworkUpload.php", "POST", formData, function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById('upload-button').innerHTML = "Upload";
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText; // post error messages too
            alert(response);
        }
    });

    setTimeout("uploadProgress()",1000);    
},false);
```

**Javascript upload progress**

```
function uploadProgress(){
    loadXMLDoc("uploadProgress.php", "POST", "", function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var percentComplete = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('bar_blank').innerHTML = percentComplete+"%";
            if (percentComplete < 100){
                setTimeout(uploadProgress, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP upload progress**

```
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "file-item";
if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    echo 100;
}
```

When I upload a large file via direct form submission, I can do `print_r($_SESSION)` and watch the bytes change as I refresh the screen. Of course, by directly submitting, the page hangs until I've finished uploading (20 seconds) so I can't access these variables on the starting page anyway. So `AJAX` is the obvious way to go, but when I submit with `XHR`, the session variables aren't created and I can't do any processing that way either! As a result, the `uploadProgress.php` just immediately returns 100%, regardless of the actual completion due to the empty `$_SESSION` variable.

What is stopping the session variables from being created when I do the `AJAX` call? How do I change this? Are `<iframe>`s the only way to do this for IE9+ (and probably earlier, I haven't looked into it yet).