# XMLHttp​Request​.upload.onprogress is triggered when server respons 500 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I use [XMLHttp​Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload) to upload a file. If server responds with error message 500, I try to handle error message before `onprogress` event.

**XMLHttpRequest**

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 500) {
              console.log('error2');
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        console.log('success');
      }
    };

      xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
          console.log(percentComplete);
        }
      };

      xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:1337/upload-file", true);
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", e.file);
      xhr.send(formData);
```

I throw error message on server on purpose:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const path = require('path');
const koaBodyMultipart = require('koa-body')({ multipart: true });

const app = new Koa();
app.use(cors());
app.use(serve(path.join(process.env.PWD, '/dist')));

const router = new Router();

router
  .post('/upload-file', koaBodyMultipart, (ctx, next) => {
    const { file } = ctx.request.files;
    // if (file) {
    //     ctx.response.body = 'ok';
    // } else {
    //     ctx.throw(500,'Error Message');
    // }
    ctx.throw(500,'Error Message');
  });

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

// don't listen to this port if the app is required from a test script
if (!module.parent) {
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('running at port:' + port)
}
```

Why is `upload.onprogress` triggered before `xhr.onreadystatechange` and `xhr.onload`? How can I show error message before showing uploading progress?

Comment: have you tried to handle upload.onerror?
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418608/xmlhttprequest-level-2-determinate-if-upload-finished

Comment: Yes I tried `upload.onerror`, but this event is not triggered, because this event is for "failure on a netwrok level", more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10584491/968379).

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple script to check the order of events. The order of events always occurs this way:

```
readystateChange: 1
loadstart
XHR OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:1337/upload-file [HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 24ms]
XHR POST http://127.0.0.1:1337/upload-file [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 20ms]
progress
load
loadend
readystateChange: 2
readystateChange: 3
readystateChange: 4
```

`Progress` event is always triggered before the `load` events.

Since the progress is updated before your error message is displayed, you can  update the progress upto a certain percentage like say 95%. Then handle the rest of the update in the `loadend` or `readyStateChange` events. For example:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = (e.loaded - e.total*0.05 / e.total) * 100;
        percentComplete = percentComplete < 0? 0: percentComplete;
        console.log(percentComplete);
    }
};

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 500) {
            // Handle error case
        } else if (xhr.status === 200){
            percentComplete = 100;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is better than nothing, but I still think it is really strange you cannot handle server error before triggering `onprogress` event. If better answer won't show up, I will award your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [XMLHttpRequest Level 2 - Determinate if upload finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418608/xmlhttprequest-level-2-determinate-if-upload-finished)

progress is called when sending and receiving data, and that is what happens when you send the file even if the response is an error. the state changed event is only fired later when all is done and the server closes the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to handle `xhr.status === 500` in various xhr event handlers, but I am not able to get error status earlier than `onprogress` event :/